# How can I get to my functions properly by friendship?

Tags: c++, vector

I have a abstract class like:

```
class Polygon {

public:
    vector < int > sides;

    virtual void circumreference()=0;
    virtual void print() = 0;
    void SaveAndRead() {
        save(sides);
        load(sides);
    }
    friend void save(std::vector < int >&);
    friend void load(std::vector < int >&);

};
```

save and load are out of class Polygon. I am trying to call function save and load in function SaveAndRead(), but I have errors like " save: ID not found" ," load: ID not found". 
Could somebody help me out with this? I will be grateful!

Comment: paste the whole error message in verbatim. Also, this is a bad design pattern: `save` and `load` should be part of Polygon, not external, or call public methods or constructors of Polygon, so that it doesn't have to be `friend`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot replace the regular declaration of `save` and `load` by only declaring them as friends of `Polygon`.
That is, you must also declare them before `Polygon`.

Then, in order for your whole program to compile, you need to define `save` and `load` in a .cpp file.

Also you probably want `save` at least to take a `const` reference.

```cpp
//polygon.hpp

#include <vector>

void save(const std::vector < int >&);
void load(std::vector < int >&);

class Polygon {

public:
    std::vector < int > sides;

    virtual void circumreference()=0;
    virtual void print() = 0;
    void SaveAndRead() {
        save(sides);
        load(sides);
    }
    friend void save(const std::vector < int >&);
    friend void load(std::vector < int >&);

};

// polygon.cpp
#include "polygon.hpp"

void save(const std::vector < int >&){
   // Code for save
}
void load(std::vector < int >&){
   // Code for load
}
```

---

Non related aspects:

- If `load` is used to initialize its argument, you probably want to return the vector by value.
- `save` and `load` seems to be good candidate to be actual members of `Polygon`. Friendship *rarely* is a good design choice.

---

More about the use of `friend`:

One typical use of `friend` is to implement iterators or any class intended to offer a specific "view" of another class. You want to give full access to this "view" class as it is conceptually part of the class it gives access to.

Some people also like to overload `operator<<` for streams using `friend` instead of defining a `print` public method called by the `operator<<` overload, which is acceptable.

Finally, commutative operators such as `operator+` can be implemented either as a public member taking the *other* instance as argument or as a free friend function taking the two instances as arguments. The first approach is more concise while the second reflects the symmetry of the operator better.

Comment: Thanks for good explanation! I did it like you just have written - I made this functions members of class Polygon. Most of programmers revieve friendship - I have just checked it out.  Thank you a lot for your time ;)

Answer (score 0):

I understand that the **save** and **load** functions lay outside in an other class. In that case you should add the name of that class to your function definition.

```
friend void StoreFunctionClass::save(std::vector<int>&);
```